# Subsequent tabs being closed in pyqt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to close a tab when the users presses the close tab button. This is the code that should do that:

```
self.tab_widget.addTab(text, TabName)
self.tab_widget.setTabsClosable(1)
self.tab_widget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.tab_widget.removeTab)
```

It works, but when I close a tab before other tab(s) it closes out all of them after it, and I am not sure why. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Oh... well I figured out why this was happening. I had the code that removes the tabs with the code that creates them and so I guess I was doing multiple connects thus getting rid of more than one tab.